# Requests in the Amidah - hide and seek

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, personal-request-bakashot

The Amidah standing prayer is at the center of our tefillos. Every Amidah has three blessings of praise (שבח) at the beginning, and the blessings of thanks (הודאה) at the end.
The weekday Amidah has thirteen blessing of requests (בקשה) in the middle. This is where we ask Hashem for all of our needs.
Roughly speaking, the initial requests are personal, and the later requests (say, starting from תקע בשופר גדול, "blow the great shofar from our freedom...", the seventh blessing in the middle) are for the whole community.
I think it's *reasonable* to assume that everything we need is in there somewhere, in one of those requests. (Is that true?) But I don't always find it easy to know where.

So that's my question: What are some "things we need" that are hard to find in the list of בקשות, and where do you think they are found there and why?
Answers could either be more hard-to-find things, or answers on someone else's, or both.
(I understand that you can pray for everything in the *last* request, שומע תפילה. But is that the answer, Chazal picked some important ones and left the rest out because they included a catch-all?)

I'll start with:
a) A prayer that my children should be successful בהצלחה אמיתית, true success. Surely that's something all of us want for our children - where is it?
Is the answer that I should only be praying for my part of it, my hishtadlus, and the rest is up to Hashem? So the correct prayer is the first request, "Grant wisdom", (חונן הדעת). Or is some other answer correct?
b) A prayer for complete victory against terrorist murderers who threaten our people and for the safety of Israel's soldiers. Is that included in "Redeemer of Israel" (גואל ישראל), fourth request?

Comment: why wouldn't b) be under v'lamalshinim?

Comment: @rosends Isn't that a late addition for _internal_ enemies?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure it's limited to that when it talks about אויבי עמך and מלכות הרשעה.

Comment: I don't think additions have to be literal, but thematic. Successful children aren't literally what Ata chonen says.

Comment: I mean I would say obviously chazal cants make a bracha for every single issue under the sun, but they chose 18 specific themes that they believed were the most important to pray for everyday, and the rest you can say privately in Shema Koleinu. I don’t see a problem with this

Comment: @CuriousYid So you are saying that my initial assumption was wrong. Not everything is included (except in Shema Koleinu).

Comment: @MichoelR imo yes. I can see people doing mental gymnastics to try to demonstrate how any problem in life could be covered by one of the brachot, but then what’s the point even of shema koleinu. The whole point of it must be to cover whatever was missed

Comment: I thought we're supposed to add in the specifics of what we need

Comment: @CuriousYid I kind of pictured that the main idea of Shema _Koleinu_ was what it says: Please listen to all of our words. We ask for all these things, then we ask Hashem to listen to us and have mercy on us.

Comment: @MosesSupposes We are, but where exactly? In the general place in Shema Koleinu, but you're also allowed to ask for something in its specific location. Pray for a sick person in Refaenu...

Comment: I always thought that Shema Koleinu is the catch all for when there is nowhere else that it fits